# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'englishcomputers.yml'

Tags: python, filepath, chatbot

```
for files in os.listdir('english'):
data=open('english'+ files,'r').readlines()
bot.train(data)
```

The first line of the for loop which opens the file produces an error.

I changed  "computers.yml" file also but its not working as it seems like it didn't get the path correctly.

Any solution for this please?

Comment: How about giving the right path? What is it, that is not understandable in the error message?

Comment: Your code is not indented it seems? Also try giving the full file name. Complete Stacktrace should also be posted.

Comment: def main():
    chatbot = ChatBot('Bot',
                      storage_adapter ='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
                      trainer = 'chatterbot.trainers.ListTrainer')
    for files in os.walk('hector/'):
        convData = open(r'hector/' + files, encoding='latin-1').readlines()
        #convData = open('hector/' + files, 'r').readlines()
        chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
        chatbot.train(convData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a `/` separating the directory and the file name in order to open the specific file from its appropriate path within the `english` directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

for files in os.listdir('english'):
    file_path=os.path.join('english',files)
    data=open(file_path,'r').readlines()
    bot.train(data)
```

Comment: What if code is executed on Windows? `os.path.join` would be more universal

Comment: Thanks @SashaTsukanov, good suggestion. I've updated my answer